# change circle color in application bar on windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

i need to change from this

[image: gray circle]

to this

[image: yellow circle]

BUT with a little nuance: nothing except the circle must change. i mean those three dots, they must stay gray. that's why `ApplicationBar.ForegroundColor` doesn't fit.

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the standard ApplicationBar. I might suggest writing your own or modifying one like the one found in [Phone7.Fx](http://phone7.codeplex.com/) or [this one](http://bindableapplicationb.codeplex.com/). Then you could have your own property on the ApplicationBar (eg: CircleBrush) that you could modify.

I would suggest not doing this as it would take away from the standard user experience of the phone. What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: i just want icon with circle to turn yellow when item is added to favourites

Comment: A better UX solution is to use a different image. You can't change the colours explicit for the Circle as Shawn writes, so you'll either have to add a non-standard ApplicationBar (not recommended), or go with a completely different solution. Also, on the white-theme a yellow button would be near-invisible!

Comment: I have to agree with Claus. It is very easy to change the icon itself and usually that is what happens what state changes. The icon itself changes to a different icon, or changes from enabled to disabled.